# Lighttpd HTTPS use X-Forwarded-Proto

Tags: ubuntu, lighttpd

I am running Lighttpd 1.4.35 (most up to date on APT) on Ubuntu 16.04 behind an AWS ELB. The load balancer is accepting connections on ports 80 and 443 and is doing SSL termination.

I am trying to detect whether the request was performed using HTTPS but Lighttpd seems to be ignoring the X-Forwarded-Proto header. This just results in infinite HTTP->HTTPS redirects. I have checked the question here: [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28414799/access-x-forwarded-proto-in-lighttpd-configiuration) but there was only one workaround, no solution.

I thought maybe using mod_extforward would help, but it doesn't seem to make a difference, apart from logging the clients IP in the logs.

Here are relevant parts of my config, any ideas to get this detecting HTTPS correctly whilst still using Lighttpd would be appreciated:

```
server.modules = (
    "mod_accesslog",
    "mod_access",
    "mod_alias",
    "mod_compress",
    "mod_extforward",
    "mod_redirect",
    "mod_rewrite"
)

extforward.headers = ("X-Forwarded-For")
extforward.forwarder = ("all" => "trust")

# Check the domain
$HTTP["host"] =~ "^domain.com$" {
    # If not HTTPS, redirect to it
    $HTTP["scheme"] != "https" {
        # Redo the host condition check to allow us to access the %1 variable
        $HTTP["host"] =~ "^domain.com$" {
            url.redirect = ("^/(.*)" => "https://%1/$1")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks like it's fixed in the 1.4.40 (released in july): http://redmine.lighttpd.net/issues/1499